# JSON Decode into php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, encode

I am using JSON square brackets and would like to decode this into a two multidimensional array.

This is the JSON:

```
"results" : [[ /* WINNER BRACKET */
    [[3,5], [2,4], [6,3], [2,3], [1,5], [5,3], [7,2], [1,2]],
    [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]],
    [[9,1], [8,2]],
    [[1,3]]
  ], [         /* LOSER BRACKET */
    [[5,1], [1,2], [3,2], [6,9]],
    [[8,2], [1,2], [6,2], [1,3]],
    [[1,2], [3,1]],
    [[3,0], [1,9]],
    [[3,2]],
    [[4,2]]
  ], [         /* FINALS */
    [[3,8], [1,2]],
    [[2,1]]
  ]]
```

And I am looking to decode the above into this type of PHP array as shown below:

```
$winner_results = array
  (
  array("match1",3,5),
  array("match2",2,4),
  array("match3",6,3),
  array("match4",2,3),
  array("match5",1,5),
  array("match6",5,3),
  array("match7",7,2),
  array("match8",1,2),
  array("match9",1,12),
  array("match10",3,4),
  array("match11",5,6),
  array("match12",7,8),
  array("match13",9,1),
  array("match14",8,2),
  array("match15",1,3)
  );

$loser_results = array
  (
  array("match16",5,1),
  array("match17",1,2),
  array("match18",3,2),
  array("match19",6,9),
  array("match20",8,2),
  array("match21",1,2),
  array("match22",6,2),
  array("match23",1,3),
  array("match24",1,2),
  array("match25",3,1),
  array("match26",3,0),
  array("match27",1,9),
  array("match28",3,2),
  array("match29",4,2)
  );

$finals_results = array
  (
  array("match30",3,8),
  array("match31",1,2),
  array("match32",2,1)
  );
```

And would it possible to encode the above PHP array into the exact same JSON format as shown?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Hint: look up `json_decode()`.

Comment: yes I have tried json_decode() but returns NULL. I am using square brackets so I cannot recall.

Comment: [Edit] your question with the code you have tried. Also, how are you getting/reading/receiving this data? And what do you mean by "I cannot recall?"

Comment: "encode the above PHP array" -- aren't those actually multiple arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution.

Note: I have used dynamic variable names ($$varname) to create own arrays for each group (winners, loosers, final).

```
<?php
$results = '[[
  [[3,5], [2,4], [6,3], [2,3], [1,5], [5,3], [7,2], [1,2]],
  [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]],
  [[9,1], [8,2]],
  [[1,3]]
], [
  [[5,1], [1,2], [3,2], [6,9]],
  [[8,2], [1,2], [6,2], [1,3]],
  [[1,2], [3,1]],
  [[3,0], [1,9]],
  [[3,2]],
  [[4,2]]
], [
  [[3,8], [1,2]],
  [[2,1]]
]]';

// These are the group names
$names  = array('winner_results','looser_results','final_results');

// First we make a PHP array out of the JSON (object) string
$resarr = json_decode($results);

// Then we create a new array for each group, re-organizing the input array $resarr
$cnt = 0;  // The counter we use for qualifying the 'match' identifiers
foreach($resarr as $groupix => $group) {
    $arrname = $names[$groupix];
    $$arrname = array();  // Create an empty array for the group
    foreach($group as $items) {
        foreach($items as $item) {
            // Add data (array) to the group array
            $cnt++;
            array_push($$arrname,array('match'.$cnt,$item[0],$item[1]));
        }
    }
}

// And finally we display the created arrays
foreach ($names as $arr) {
    echo '<h3>'.$arr.'</h3><pre>'; print_r($$arr); echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an `array_merge' of the 'sub-arrays' of each of the`winner, losers, final` arrays.

#### The Code:

```
$allResults = json_decode($json, true);
$results = current($allResults); // get the three sub-arrays

$winner = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results[0]);
$loser  = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results[1]);
$finals = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results[2]);
```

#### Test data (Converted to valid JSON)

```
$json = '{"results": [[
  [[3,5], [2,4], [6,3], [2,3], [1,5], [5,3], [7,2], [1,2]],
  [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]],
  [[9,1], [8,2]],
  [[1,3]]
], [
  [[5,1], [1,2], [3,2], [6,9]],
  [[8,2], [1,2], [6,2], [1,3]],
  [[1,2], [3,1]],
  [[3,0], [1,9]],
  [[3,2]],
  [[4,2]]
], [
  [[3,8], [1,2]],
  [[2,1]]
]]}';
```

Comment: works fine thanks a lot!